# Will Allah forgive me for this dishonesty?

Tags: allah

During my SSC exam i told my mom to contact with teachers to give me practical mark. My mom contacted them. Well we didn’t harm anyone nor gave any money to them. But my mom gave sweets to them. I am extremely sorry for this today. Will Allah forgive me?

Answer (score 1):

"Tell them (O Prophet)," My servants who have committed excesses against themselves (committed sins)do not lose hope in Allah's mercy. Surely Allah forgives all sins(with repentance). He is the most forgiving,most merciful."Quran(39:53)